# rjags model negative binomial likelihood and gamma prior

Tags: r, jags, rjags

I read in my data. I make the model string. I hand it JAGS. I get "Error in node y[1] - Node inconsistent with parents".

```
Y=read.table("data.txt",header=T)
Y=Y$Y


model_string <- "model{

# Likelihood:
for( i in 1 : N ) {
y[i] ~ dnegbin( l , r )
}

# Prior:
r ~ dgamma(1,1)
l ~ dgamma(.1,.1)
}"

model <- jags.model(textConnection(model_string), 
                    data = list(y=Y,N=200))
```

First off all, I have no clue if my model is right. I cannot find even basic documentation for JAGS. I'm actually ashamed to admit it, because this should be as simple as an internet search, but I cannot find any document to tell me 1) how a JAGS model is set up or 2) what kinds of functions/distribution/parameters are available in JAGS. I only got this far because I found someone doing a similar model. If anyone knows of a JAGS wiki or documentation, that would be great.

Edit: If someone could even just tell me what the parameters for dnegbin are that would be a huge help. When I plug in random numbers for `l` and `r` in `dnegbin(l,r)` it 'works' as in it draws numbers for `l` and `r`, but I have no clue if it means anything.

Comment: Are you sure that your `y` are non-negative integers ?

Comment: Also I think that the first parameter of `dnegbin` is the success parameter, so it should lie between `0` and `1`, and then the Gamma prior is not appropriate.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Non-negative yes, but some are 0. While the gamma prior is not conjugate, it should still work. I should be able to get JAGS to do MH to draw from it, but I have no clue how to specify MH.

Comment: The Gamma disitrbution takes values > 1. That is the problem. You have to assign a prior distribution which takes its values between 0 and 1.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent No, it's drawing numbers now. I just still have no clue what it is doing.

Comment: See the [JAGS user manual](https://web.sgh.waw.pl/~atoroj/ekonometria_bayesowska/jags_user_manual.pdf). **The first parameter of dnegbin must be between 0 and 1**.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Thanks. If you had an answer, I'd accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find some info about `dnegbin` in the [JAGS user manual](https://web.sgh.waw.pl/~atoroj/ekonometria_bayesowska/jags_user_manual.pdf).

The first parameter of `dnegbin` must be between and 0 and 1. You can assign e.g. a uniform distribution:

```
library(rjags)

model_string <- "model{

# Likelihood:
for( i in 1 : N ) {
y[i] ~ dnegbin( l , r )
}

# Prior:
r ~ dgamma(1,1)
l ~ dunif(0,1)
}"

y <- rpois(200, 10)
model <- jags.model(textConnection(model_string), 
                    data = list(y=y, N=length(y)))
```

You also have to be sure that the values of `y` are non-negative *integers*.